# How do you use Countif with two matching criterias in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The current formula is =COUNTIF(Sheet2!C[-1],Sheet1!RC[-1])

```
Fruit   Color   Sold
Apple   Red     Yes
Shoe    Red     Yes

Fruit   Color   Count
Apple   Green   0
Apple   Red     2
```

The count should be "1" for red apples. How does the formula get fixed so the column "Fruit" also matches?

Comment: Use COUNTIFS perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that notation you can use:
`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!C[-1],Sheet1!RC[-1],Sheet2!C[-2],Sheet1!RC[-2])`